# what is the standard guideline to declare the "==" condition?

Tags: java, c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between these (bCondition == NULL) and (NULL==bCondition)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854317/what-is-the-difference-between-these-bcondition-null-and-null-bcondition)

please see the below code:-

```
if(myVariable==5)
   {
     //some logic
   }
```

one of my friends says that this is not a good way to write the code as its not per guidelines, however he dont have any reason to it. Is there is a chance of exception with above code or accidental modification?? According to him the better way would have been

```
if(5==myVariable)
       {
         //some logic
       }
```

please let me know which is a better way and why??? Do provide links if u have any.

Comment: Either way is valid, but I have seen the former used 99% of the time.

Comment: Basically, all answers in this post are saying one thing: both statements are the same, just stick with the one which is more readable. The most common and used one is if(variable == 5), which also happens to be more readable (you can see what are you considering, and what are you checking it against). Btw, both ways are correct.

Comment: They are called [Yoda conditions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378/new-programming-jargon-you-coined/2430307#2430307) and are considered silly.

Comment: @Bo Persson: First time I have heard that. But I like it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only reason to write:

```
5 == variable
```

instead of

```
variable == 5
```

is that in the former case if you incorrectly put an *assignment* (single `=`) in place you will get a compile time error because you are trying to overwrite a constant.

However any decent compiler will give you a warning if you do:

```
if (variable = 5)
```

so IMHO it's not worth worrying about.  I *always* use the latter `if (var == num)` form.

---

However in Java there *is* a common pattern that *is* worth using.  When testing a string for equality, one should use:

```
if ("constant".equals(variable)) { ... }
```

instead of:

```
if (variable.equals("constant")) { ... }
```

since the latter can trigger a null pointer exception, and the former cannot.

Comment: +1 for saying `any decent compiler will give you a warning`

Comment: +1 for thoroughness and "any decent compiler will give you a warning".

Answer (score 4):

The reversal is preferable in some languages like C, where

```
if (x = 5) {
   ...
}
```

would *accidentally* assign x to the value 5 if you mistype `=` instead of `==`. By reversing the two arguments the compiler would rightfully object to you reassigning the value 5.

Unlike C/C++, for languages such as Java it's not such an issue since

```
if (x = 5) {
   ...
}
```

isn't a valid statement. I still follow the above practise however. I don't have to rethink when swapping between Java and C/C++.

Comment: It is not less of an issue in Java for boolean expressions. If I follow the Java Spec correctly, then something like `boolean b = ...; if (b=true)` is valid code (same for C#, btw).

Answer (score 2):

Both are same. select which ever you find more readable.. I would go with first

Answer (score 2):

For that specific case, it's *technically* safer to do `5 == variable` because then if you accidentally say `5 = variable` the compiler will complain. On the other hand, `variable = 5` is perfectly legal.

Comment: It doesn't stop me from writing `5 == variable` when I meant to write `5 != variable`.

Comment: That's why I said *technically* because it's one less use-case you have to deal with. Your argument is true for `variable != 5` a well. Either way, worrying about this kind of stuff seems a bit paranoid, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

This convention is to prevent you from accidentally writing `if (myVariable=5)` when you mean `if (myVariable==5)`.

Answer (score 1):

For `==`, it doesn't matter a bit what order you do it in.

Your friend mentioned "guidelines"-- perhaps it's a business rule? Albeit an arbitrary and semi-pointless one...

Answer (score 1):

It's immaterial.   I prefer the first one, because it's more readable.

I hope you're aware that using `==` is not always correct for reference types.  In those cases you should prefer `equals`.  THEN it matters, because you want to avoid null pointer exceptions.  It's best to dereference the instance that cannot be null in that case.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such guildline I found.
First approach should be followed because it is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

i think if you what to know if they are equals it's fine then.
but if you want to know about string, then i more appropriated use '.equals'.

e.g:

```
object.equals("something");
```

Comment: or preferably, `"something".equals(object)`, since this is one of those cases where it's better to put a constant on the right-hand side of the `.equals()`.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is to avoid possible syntax errors of the kind `constant = expression`, or to avoid mangled operator overload in C++. In Java both expressions are syntatically valid and picking one over the other is a matter of choice.