# Proper form in C++

Tags: c++, defensive-programming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between these (bCondition == NULL) and (NULL==bCondition)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854317/what-is-the-difference-between-these-bcondition-null-and-null-bcondition)

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193170/defensive-programming-whats-the-purpose-of-using-for-a-single-line) it says "const object on left side of comparison" is some how "better" than doing otherwise. Why is this?

Comment: Saying `if (5 == i)` isn't as much any more used. It's supposed to stop from saying you `if (i = 5)` by mistake. Sometimes called "Yoda Conditions" it is. A page of that and some others [here is](http://www.dodgycoder.net/2011/11/yoda-conditions-pokemon-exception.html).

Comment: Google for: "Yoda Conditions"

Comment: Yoda conditions are often considered poor practice now, since they are less readable and most compilers warn about assignment anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any decent compiler will warn you about assignment within a conditional expression, so that form isn't very relevant these days.

> On another point "use unsigned for variables that are >= 0 // nice trick " I heard that using unsigned can be confusing and shouldn't use unless there's a reason. Does anyone agree or refute this?

Use `unsigned` when the value should be `unsigned`.

Answer (score 0):

This is to avoid the "=" versus "==" mistake.    If you mean "==" but type "=" and the object on the LHS is constant, the compiler will complain.  For example,

```
if ( 3 == x )
```

is preferred to

```
if ( x == 3 )
```

because if you type

```
if ( 3 = x )
```

then you'll get an error, but if you type

```
if ( x = 3 )
```

then you may get a bug!